# How to check if Git is enabled on an ongoing XCode project

Tags: xcode, git

What is a quick way to check if git is enabled or not on a currently ongoing XCode project I started a while back and therefore cannot remember if I checked the git checkbox or not?

Comment: hit alt + cmd + c and test if the commit window appears..

Comment: or edit a file and see if `[m]` marker appears near that file in project navigator.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.  Probably the most relevant one is the go to the 'Organizer' and click on 'Repositories'.  If you created a repository it will be there (and you will be able to see its structure).

If you are comfortable with the 'Terminal' app you can switch to the Project's folder/directory and do 'ls -lF .git'.  If something is reported than there is a GIT repository.

Finally, in Xcode, you can click on the Project itself, view the 'Utilities' pane, select 'File Inspector', open the 'Source Control' pane and see what it says.